# Change colors with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I was unclear. Say I have three rows, and use the checkbox on row two, then I only want that row to change color, the others shall remain unchanged. Sorry for my poor explanation.

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" value="check" onclick="ChangeBackgroundColor(this)">'

function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
    if (status.checked == true) {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTableData").getElementsByTagName("tr")
        x[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Comment: You need to loop through all the elements contained in `x` and set their colour.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Say I have three rows, and use the checkbox on row two, then I only want that row to change color, the others shall remain unchanged. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 1):

try to iterate over tags:

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor(status) {
    if (status.checked == true) {
        var x=document.getElementById("myTableData").getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i=0; i<x.length; ++i) {
            x[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
To get selected row color change using jQuery it will be something like:

```
$('#myTableData').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
   var self = $(this);
   if (self.is(':checked')) {
      self.closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Say I have three rows, and use the checkbox on row two, then I only want that row to change color, the others shall remain unchanged. Sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @jcubic however, if you don't mind me asking, this changes the checkbox color, what if I wanted the whole row the change? I've tried using "previoussibling" but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @korvar it should change color of the row not checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all the elements contained in `x` and set their colour:

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
    if (status.checked) {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTableData").getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Or as you tagged jQuery:

```
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" value="check" />'

$('#myTableData').on('change', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#myTableData tr').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

To change only the parent row use this:

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor(status){
    if (status.checked) {
        status.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}

// jQuery alternative:
$('#myTableData').on('change', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe I was unclear. Say I have three rows, and use the checkbox on row two, then I only want that row to change color, the others shall remain unchanged. Sorry for my poor explanation.